# Le diable au corps

Tags: sens

Excuse me I don't intend to earn merits here, as I don't speak french, but this one questions bothers me since a long time.

What does this tell me: "le diable au corps"?

Is it the devil in flesh and blood (like, standing before me), or is it the devil *possessing* a body, someone having the devil inside his/her/its body?

Comment: Welcome to FSE.

Comment: *Le diable en corps* doesn't exist in French. As you accepted an answer that assume you meant *le diable au corps*, better to correct your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full turn is: "avoir le diable au corps". For example, *il a le diable au corps*.

> Signification : Déployer une énergie, une activité intense, une
>   vivacité surhumaine. Peut qualifier quelqu'un qui a des valeurs
>   amorales.
>
> Origine : Expression française du XIVème siècle qui puise ses origines
>   dans les croyances populaires de l'époque. En effet, depuis toujours,
>   les gens ont accordé au diable des pouvoirs extraordinaires. De ce
>   fait si ce demon tendait à s'emparer du corps humain, celui-ci se
>   remplirait d'une vivacité surnaturelle. Il est à remarquer qu'au début
>   du XXème siècle, au cours des années 1920 appelées années folles,
>   avoir le diable au corps prend une connotation érotique en assimilant
>   le corps à la chair et le diable au désir. De ce fait, cette
>   expression française tend à prendre plusieurs insinuations en fonction
>   de son intonation: Admirative pour la personne vivace, sévère envers
>   la turbulence d'un enfant et contenant de la désapprobation envers
>   l'adultère.
>
> http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-a/1108-avoir-le-diable-au-corps.html

Translation:

Meaning: Deploy energy, intense activity, superhuman vivacity. Can qualify someone who has amoral values.
Origin: French expression of the XIVth century which draws its origins from the popular beliefs of the time. In fact, people have always granted extraordinary powers to the devil. Therefore if this demon tended to seize the human body, it would be filled with a supernatural vivacity. It should be noted that at the beginning of the 20th century, during the 1920s called the Roaring Twenties, having the devil in the body took on an erotic connotation by assimilating the body to the flesh and the devil to desire. Therefore, this French expression tends to take several innuendos according to its intonation: Admirative for the perennial person, severe towards the turbulence of a child and containing disapproval towards adultery.

See also here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_le_diable_au_corps (in English).

Here: https://www.modele-lettre-gratuit.com/expressions-francaises/avoir-le-diable-au-corps.html (in French).

And here: https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/36468 (in French).

DeepL may be useful for the translation: https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator. You can find in the French articles several examples of usage taken from the literature.

So, to distinguish it, the term for the devil in flesh and blood could be "le diable en chair et en os" (Thanks @Greg).

Comment: Thank you, so what would be, to distinguish it, the term for the devil in flesh and blood?

Comment: You could say "le diable en chair et en os".

Comment: @Greg French is very, very different to (the few) other languages I know. And my teacher was not so good at teaching, more insisting on learning by heart, like storing things in a data base without understanding.. What would equal "incarnate"?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Mnemonics rules or rules of thumbs are quite useful when one learns French. Things as MRSDRVANDERTRAMPP (for verbs conjugating with être in compound tenses) and BAGS (for adjectives preceding nouns) may be in handy in the beginning.

Comment: @GyroGearloose incarner (?) L'incarnation est l'acte par lequel le Fils de Dieu a revêtu volontairement un corps humain (Jn 1:14; Ph 2:7; 1 Ti 3:16). "La Parole a été faite chair et elle a habité parmi nous." Le mot "incarnation" est un terme théologique qui ne figure pas dans la Bible; il vient du latin "caro, carnis" = "chair" qui est aussi à la racine des mots "carnassier, carnivore, carné". https://www.bible-ouverte.ch/cours-formation-biblique/cours-credo-chapitre-2/1434-2-2-1-lincarnation.html

Comment: @Dimitris Yes, this is exactly in the spirit of the thing. Although, I have to guess "revêtu".

Comment: The phrase "en chair et en os" means "in person", in physical presence (eg: *J'ai vu Brad Pitt en chair et en os*). see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_chair_et_en_os. "Incarnate" would translate as "incarné". It can also be used to qualify the devil, but rather as a metaphor, when talking about someone you want compare to a devil (ex: *leur fils est incontrôlable, c'est le diable incarné*).

Comment: @Dimitris I don't intend to learn french. I failed greatly at school and any retry would need a good reason, something like a job in France or in a french speaking community, or a general understanding of language as such.

Comment: @Greg so "en chair et en os" is a wording in want of a proper single word?

Comment: When I look up a word in a German dictionary, I end up with mostly three propositions, but with french, there are at least three proposed translations.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: sorry, I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by  "wording in want of a proper single word" ?

Comment: @Greg well in German language there is "der Leibhaftige" as opposite to "den Teufel im Leib". The first mentions the devil as having a corpse propper, the second refers to the devil *inside*  the corps, being possessed, to some degree.

Comment: I can't think of a single word that would encompass the same concept in French, hence the advice for phrases such as "le diable en chair et en os" if you need to stress the physical incarnation. My understanding, however is that *der Leibhaftige* is also some sort of euphemism to mention the devil. There is then also a euphemistic word in French: *le Malin* - but it does not imply his physical embodiment, it stresses his evil morality.

Comment: @GyroGearloose "diable en chair et en os" could also be "incarnation du diable", diable "incarné"